# clear properties from stylesheets

Tags: css

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a script to clear all the properties from a css stylesheet, but leave the selectors.

For instance:

```
body {background: #000; font-size:10px; width:100%;}
```

becomes:

```
body {}
```

This would be done to the whole stylesheet. Thanks if anyone knows of a script to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Deleting or renaming (breaking the link to) the entire CSS file will have the same effect.
- The [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) addon for Firefox will allow you to disable CSS entirely for a page if you are interested in checking its contents without style information applied.
- If you really must clean out the contents between brackets, a regular expression search-and-replace text editor will do the trick. [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com) has such a feature.* Search for `{[\s\S]+}` and replace with `{ }`. Note, if your styles are across multiple lines, you will have to modify the regular expression to handle multiple lines.

**The example provided is using UltraEdit's "Unix-style" regular expression option, not the built-in one.*